# Prism: Closing Dialog Through Event

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm trying to build a simple dialog with a loading animation to show while a task is running.
I use the Prism `IDialogService` and `IEventAggregator`
However, I get a `System.InvalidOperationException` as the dialog with the animation pops up but never get's closed when the task is finished.

The Exception message is: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

The dialog can be closed by clicking on it's X Button with no issues.

In non-async situations, I can open and close dialogs as I want, but I can't wrap my head around doing this async.

This is what I came up with so far, leading to the aforementioned Error.

**WarehouseViewModel.cs**

The Data is loaded and the dialog gets shown.

```
        private async void LoadData()
        {
            await WarehouseListLoad().ContinueWith(t => { _eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoadingFinishedEvent>().Publish(true); });
        }

        private async Task WarehouseListLoad()
        {
            _dialogService.ShowDialog("LoadingDialogView");
            List<Warehouse> warehouses = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                List<Warehouse> list = _warehouseStore.GetAll();
                return list;
            });
        }
```

**LoadingDialogViewModel.cs**

Listen for the LoadingFinishedEvent and invoke RequestClose.

```
        public event Action<IDialogResult> RequestClose;

        public LoadingDialogViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoadingFinishedEvent>().Subscribe(close => CloseDialog(null));
        }

        protected virtual void CloseDialog(string parameter)
        {
            RaiseRequestClose(new DialogResult(ButtonResult.None));
        }

        public virtual void RaiseRequestClose(IDialogResult dialogResult)
        {
            try
            {
                RequestClose?.Invoke(dialogResult);
            }
            catch(System.InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                //System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you mix `async`/`await` with `ContinueWith` here? Is this meant to obfuscate the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either want to `Subscribe` on the UI-Thread

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoadingFinishedEvent>().Subscribe(close => CloseDialog(null), ThreadOption.UIThread);
```

or use the `Dispatcher` to invoke `RequestClose`.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( () => RequestClose?.Invoke(dialogresult) );
```

Or you drop `Task.Run` and make `GetAll` actually asynchronous...

Comment: I don'k know how i read past this in the [documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/event-aggregator.html). Thanks a lot!